# при вставке скрипта, сайт не работает, как его адаптировать под Smarty?

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

почему не работает в шаблонизаторе Smary?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
      '.chosen-select'           : {},
      '.chosen-select-deselect'  : {allow_single_deselect:true},
      '.chosen-select-no-single' : {disable_search_threshold:10},
      '.chosen-select-no-results': {no_results_text:'Oops, nothing found!'},
      '.chosen-select-width'     : {width:"95%"}
    }
    for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вставьте literal

```
{literal}
<script>
// your script
</script>
{/literal}
```